# Can I prepend a line without creating a new line?

Tags: sed

If I have a text file containing:

```
This is a line
```

Using sed, how can I do this:

```
<p>This is a line</p>
```

I have tried the following script:

```
i\<p> a\</p>
```

but this gives me

```
<p>
This is a line
</p>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `s///` not append or insert.

```
$ echo 'This is a line' | sed 's~.*~<p>&</p>~'
<p>This is a line</p>
```

`&` at the replacement part refers  the whole match.

**OR**

You could also do like this,

```
$ echo 'This is a line' | sed 's~^~<p>~;s~$~</p>~'
<p>This is a line</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk`:

```
echo 'This is a line' | awk '$0="<p>"$0"</p>"'
<p>This is a line</p>
```

Or more robust:

```
echo 'This is a line' | awk '{$0="<p>"$0"</p>"}1'
<p>This is a line</p>
```